# ADDLOCAL sharpsetup re-setting

Tags: windows-installer, feature-selection

i am using sharpsetup 2 to execute a msi compound by features. i do silentinstall using the cmd and ADDLOCAL to specify the features i want and it is working fine

the problem is when i use sharpsetup and i passed the parameter ADDLOCAL. when msi is execute it is taking the parameter i send, but later its change it again and select all features by default

```
msiOi.Properties.Add("SERVERNAME", Configuration.Instance.DbServerName);
                msiOi.Properties.Add("INSTANCENAME", Configuration.Instance.InstanceName);
                List<string> FeaturesSeleted = new List<string>();

                if(Configuration.Instance.ProductFeatures.InstallMeasconftool)
                {
                    FeaturesSeleted.Add("ProductFeatureMCT");//Id Feature Inside the installer
                }

                if (Configuration.Instance.ProductFeatures.InstallSam)
                {
                    FeaturesSeleted.Add("ProductFeatureSAM");//Id Feature Inside the installer
                }
                msiOi.Properties.Add("ADDLOCAL", string.Join(",", FeaturesSeleted));
```

here is the msi log:

MSI (c) (E0:14) [10:05:19:488]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding ADDLOCAL property. Its value is 'ProductFeatureMCT'.

MSI (c) (E0:14) [10:05:19:628]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying ADDLOCAL property. Its current value is 'ProductFeatureMCT'. Its new value: 'MainFeatureTree,ProductFeatureMCT,ProductFeatureSAM'.

if any can help me i really appreciate

Comment: Leopoldo, what event triggers just before the ADDLOCAL is changed? My guess the problem is there.

Comment: the events triggers before ADDLOCAL changed are this MSI (c) (A0:18) [08:31:08:163]: Creating MSIHANDLE (18221) of type 790540 for thread 2840
MSI (c) (A0:18) [08:31:08:163]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding UNINSTALLPATH property. Its value is 'C:\ProgramData\{4f68ffb9-44b7-4032-b3ad-ec3c3c90f262}\Gui.exe'.
MSI (c) (A0:24) [08:31:08:163]: Creating MSIHANDLE (18222) of type 790531 for thread 2852
MSI (c) (A0:24) [08:31:08:163]: Closing MSIHANDLE (18222) of type 790531 for thread 2852

Comment: Is there a prior install of the package on the box?

Comment: If you doing the ADDLOCAL with a custom action then you may be doing it too late. It is intended to be set "early" in the install, such as the command line or during feature selection. After the costing actions is too late.

Comment: dont have a prior install on the box

Comment: i am not using a custom action, i just using a sharpsetup object to set the properties to installer begin the installation.